# Malloc in uC/OS-III RTOS of Micrium

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, rtos, micrium

We are using the uC/OS-III RTOS of Micrium. 
We are trying to the return value of malloc on the RTOS. 
When we do a malloc of 99999 (too much for the RAM) before the RTOS is started, we get a null pointer back, which is what we expect.

When we do this same malloc when the RTOS is started and in a task, we do not get a null pointer back, which we do not expect. 
The system does freeze at this moment though.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

For the info: we are using a RX62N micro controller of Renesas and the GNURX compiler

The program does not actually freeze. The program 'thinks' it gets a useful pointer (not a NULL pointer), and continues running. On a certain point the program changes its Program Counter to 00000000 and stops. So it does not get in a Exception, and therefore we can not catch it.

However there is something different when the *malloc* is called before the RTOS starts and when the RTOS is started. The difference is in the really deep assembly code of *malloc*.

On a certain point the following instructions are executed

```
CMP         R1,R7
BGTU.B      0FFF802C0H
ADD         R14,R7
```

When we are trying to allocate too much RAM the **BGTU.B** instruction should not branch and the program then continues with the **ADD** instruction. This works perfectly when *malloc* is executed before starting the RTOS and fails when we do it afterwards.

```
These are the values I get in several cases

Outside RTOS (allocable number: 10)
R1: 00008348
R7: 00000014

Outside RTOS (not allocable number: 9999)
R1: 00008348
R7: 00002718

Inside RTOS (allocable number: 10)
R1: FFFFF9D0
R7: 00000014

Inside RTOS (not allocable number: 9999)
R1: FFFFF9D0
R7: 00002718
```

I hope the whole situation is clear, I tried to explain it as good as I can :P

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does it "freeze"? What does your debugger tell you about the location and call stack?  Depending on your target, an invalid address access may have caused an exception. Default exception handlers are often empty loops - implement something more useful. Note that malloc() and free() are not usually intrinsically thread-safe.  Some libraries provide hooks to use the OS's mutex to make some non-thread-safe functions thread-safe.  Check your libraries documentation.

Comment: See the edit on top Clifford! =D

Comment: The branch is dependent on the result of the CMP operation, so you have to ask yourself not why it branched (that was because R1 > R7), but rather why the values in R1 and R7 are not as you expect.

Comment: Because I can't get spacing in this text, here is a link to pastebin for a better overview.
http://pastebin.com/mfvf0T0M

Comment: I think my edit is an acceptable presentation of the data without resorting to a temporary storage space, which would render this question less useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all but the second case in the illustration case R7 appears to contain the size of the allocation (requested size + alignment + heap management data).  Intuitively R7=0x2718 would correspond to an allocation of 999 bytes so I suspect that this might be a typo.

R1 I would guess contains the size of the heap block the memory will be allocated in, since then the CMP would make sense.  If the block is not large enough, it will fail.

However when the RTOS is running, the value in R1 becomes very large, and is obviously not correct.  This could happen if your heap became corrupted.  This will happen if you overrun a buffer allocated on the heap.  If you are allocating thread stacks from the heap, and a stack is too small, that would have the same effect.  Your thread stacks must be large enough for the worst-case call stack, plus whatever is required by the RTOS to support a context switch.  Even if you are not allocating stacks from the heap, if a thread stack is adjacent to the heap memory, a stack overflow could have the same effect.

Another way the heap may be corrupted is by concurrently performing allocation or deallocation in more than one thread without enforcing mutual exclusion or a critical section.  It is unlikely that the standard library heap management is thread-safe unless you have made the necessary modifications to integrate it with your RTOS - this may be the case if the RTOS and standard library are from the same vendor (for example if both were supplied with the compiler).

Comment: We now found a new function to allocate memory, only freeing is a problem. Probably Micrium already knew this is a problem. Because this new function is nowhere noticed in the Micrium book, we found this function this late. Probably the first option is happening with this RTOS, we didn't researched it more because we now found the new function. Freeing problem is asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717409/allocation-and-free-in-micrim-c-os-iii-rtos

Answer (score 0):

We are finding that malloc works fine when called before the UCOS-III OS is started. When called from a thread it fails and return a NULL pointer. I suspect this is due to a check against the stack which is of course not valid when running in a thread which can have an arbitrarily placed stack.
I can see in the map file that the library is referring to an specific sbrk (lib_a-sbrk.o)function and I cant find any source for that function.
It is commonly known that the default GNU sbrk function will check against the current stack pointer to see if the current break is beyond the SP and fail.

Unfortunately we have to rely on malloc as we are using a complex C++ library, as we have megabytes of memory we are not concerned about fragmentation, we just want malloc to work. We are actually not even concerned about re-entrancy as we are only using malloc in a single thread.

Would it be possible to shed some light on how the heap functions are implemented in libraries. We are using the ARM-9 chip.

Comment: This should be posted as [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), not as an answer to an existing question.