# Allocation and Free in Micriμm μC/OS-III RTOS

Tags: c, memory-management, rtos, micrium, ucos

We are using the μC/OS-III RTOS of Micrium with a RX62N of Renesas.

We built a system where we have to dynamicly alloc and free data. We found out the functions **malloc()** and **free()** are not working well with the RTOS.
However the RTOS has a custom function for this; the **Mem_HeapAlloc()** function.
This function allocates some memory of the RTOS' made *'heap'*. Problem is that it does not have a free function, probably because everything goes into a **heap pool**.

In the RTOS it is also possible to make a pool. Problem of this pool is that all the containing blocks need to be the same size. Since we are allocating and freeing different sizes, this is not a good solution for us.

We found a document which describes the memory RTOS functions [HERE](http://www.2shared.com/document/w4jSSx96/uC-LIB-Manual.html)
Chapter 4 describes the functions.

Does somebody have any idea how we could fix this problem ?

Some solutions we allready had

- **Make all the blocks sizes the same as the biggest allocation.**
  We have a lot of overhead since the smallest and biggest allocation differ a lot.
- **Don't do a free.**
  This is no solution, there will be a memory leak.

Hope somebody can help us. If something is not clear, please ask me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

- `you can allocate your objects in multiples of block sizes.`

You would still have some internal fragmentation due to which you will not be able to fully utilize available space.

You would still have following advantages using memory pools

- Memory pools allow memory allocation with constant execution time (no fragmentation). The memory release for thousands of objects in a pool is just one operation, not one by one if malloc is used to allocate memory for each object.
- Memory pools can be grouped in hierarchical tree structures, which is suitable for special programming structures like loops and recursions.
- Fixed-size block memory pools do not need to store allocation metadata for each allocation, describing characteristics like the size of the allocated block. Particularly for small allocations, this provides a substantial space savings.

Comment: We are allocating space for structs, so the allocation has to be continues.

Comment: I guess it would be responsibility of heap manager that you are using to split allocation of your struct in multiple objects.

Comment: We are not really using a heap manager, the space is just provided by the RTOS functions and these do not keep any administration.